# Match on 2 values

Tags: linq

I'm trying to figure out how to modify this to match on 2:

```
var result = _context.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CarId == carId);
```

I'm not sure how to tack this on.  I just want to base it on c.CarId == carId && c.UserId == userId

where carId and userId are incoming params to my method that this LINQ statement resides in.  I want to keep this as a lambda expression syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it exactly as you've written it:

```
var result = _context.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CarId == carId && c.UserId == userId);
```

There's nothing wrong with that. The lambda expression isn't restricted to compare a single property.

If you want to learn about LINQ in more detail, I'd *start* with LINQ to Objects, which is simpler to understand and predict. There are various tutorials around for it, and I have a [blog series called Edulinq](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx) which examines each operator in detail.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: There are some things you *can't* do, but you'll have to find something a bit more obscure ;)